# Cos'è "una camicia stirata ad arte"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Colpa dell'amido, la sua **camicia è stata stirata ad arte**, e lo sparato è così rigido da non piegarsi nemmeno sotto il peso di un torace grosso quanto il suo.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire che la "camicia è stata stirata ad arte". Alla [voce "arte" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arte/) ho trovato

> Come locuz. avv., *ad arte*, con artificio, o apposta, deliberatamente: *diffondere ad a. voci calunniose, notizie false*.

Tuttavia, non capisco il significato in questo contesto. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Arte](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/A/arte.php):

> - estens. Capacità nel fare qualcosa; abilità, destrezza.

Stirata ad arte significa una camicia stirata benissimo.

Fare qualcosa "ad arte" si usa in riferimento a qualcosa che viene  fatto con grande cura ed attenzione. A seconda del contesto puo avere una connotazione positiva o negativa.

Vedi anche ***"[Come stirare ad arte](http://tuttopercasa.pianetadonna.it/come-stirare-ad-arte-49812.html)"***:

> - In questo articolo vogliamo aiutarvi a capire in che modo poter ***imparare a stirare ad arte***, per poter avere sempre dei capi lavati, stirati e perfetti!

Anche: ***a regola d'arte***.